# How to check if string exists in table which is added using addslashes?

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework

I am storing names in a database-column called 'name' using the following function:

```
public function insertCategory($arrCat) { 
  $id = $this->insert($arrCat);
  return $id;
}
```

`$arrCat` is passed from my controller:

```
$arrCat = array(
    'name' => addslashes($name),
    'type' => $type,
    'rank' => $catOrder,
    'created_by' => $created_by,
    'created' => Zend_Date::now()->toString('yyyy:MM:dd HH:mm:ss'),
        'active' => 'y',
        'app_id' => $appId
);
```

This code inserts data properly. But I want 'name' to be unique values so I have written a function checkNameExists($name, $created_by, $app_id):

```
public function checkNameExists($name,$created_by,$app_id) {
   $sql= $this->_db->select("name")
                   ->from("titles")
                   ->where("name LIKE '" . addslashes($name) . "' AND created_by='" . $created_by . "' AND app_id = '".$app_id."' ");

   //Tried with this query as well 
   //$sql="select name from titles where name = '$name' AND created_by=$created_by AND app_id=$app_id";

   $result = $this->_db->fetchAll($sql);

   if(count($result) > 0){
        return 1;
   } else {
        return 0;
   }
}
```

So depending on the value returned by **checkNameExists()** I want to perform an insert or return a 'Name already exists'-message to the user. But the function **checkNameExists** is always returning 0 even if the same name exists in my table.

I am using Zend Framework 1 and MySQL.

Comment: There has to be a way to use prepared queries now-a-days.  addslashes() doesn't do enough to protect against injections.  Either way, addslashes shouldn't affect the result of the query.

Comment: I had used addslashes() bcoz if I enter single quoted or double quoted string then insertion was failing.

Comment: I could not understand now its working without addslashes() even if entered string contains single quote or double quote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Zend_Db_Select` has a nice fluent interface to it. First thing you need to do is use its prepared statements a bit better:

```
$sql = $this->_db->select()
    ->from('titles', array('name'))
    ->where('name       = ?', $name)
    ->where('created_by = ?', $created_by)
    ->where('app_id     = ?', $app_id);
```

This will help with the SQL injection issue. Because `Zend_Db` uses prepared statements when inserting, you don't need to use `addslashes`, just pass it in raw. This will simplify getting it out of the db because you then don't need to `stripslashes`. Also, because you are comparing un-slashed strings, all you need is the `=` operator as `LIKE` is only effective if you use a `%` as a wildcard.

Answer (score 1):

You should not use addslashes or equivalent in some array or variable but only when you are building a String query.

Moreover you should use the specific function for your database for example (https://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php for mysql).

Finally i think you are querying your database for three parameters ($name, $created_by,$app_id) and the function checkNameExists will send you 1 if the three are true, can you verify if the value of the three parameters?